# Select Only One Thread and Attachment

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a way to fetch 7 threads from `threads` table with one attachment (if more then one attachments posted in a thread). I'm using this query;

**QUERY :**

```
$query = $db->query("
    SELECT a.thumbnail, t.tid, t.subject
    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."attachments a
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts p ON(p.pid=a.pid)
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t ON(t.tid=p.tid)
    WHERE {$where_sql} {$visible}
    ORDER BY a.dateuploaded ASC, t.tid DESC
    LIMIT 7
");
```

---

It does fetches attachments and threads but the issue is it fetches all attachments of a thread.

Is there any workaround?

---

Where Clause:

```
if ($mybb->user['usergroup'] == "4")
{
    $visible = " AND p.visible = '1' OR p.visible = '0'";
}
else
{
    $visible = " AND p.visible = '1'";
}

$where_sql = "t.fid IN({$pdf_fid})";

require_once MYBB_ROOT."inc/functions_search.php";
$unsearchforums = get_unsearchable_forums();
if($unsearchforums)
{
    $where_sql .= " AND t.fid NOT IN ($unsearchforums)";
}
$inactiveforums = get_inactive_forums();
if($inactiveforums)
{
    $where_sql .= " AND t.fid NOT IN ($inactiveforums)";
}

$permsql = "";
$onlyusfids = array();

// Check group permissions if we can't view threads not started by us
$group_permissions = forum_permissions();
foreach($group_permissions as $fid => $forum_permissions)
{
    if($forum_permissions['canonlyviewownthreads'] == 1)
    {
        $onlyusfids[] = $fid;
    }
}
if(!empty($onlyusfids))
{
    $where_sql .= "AND ((t.fid IN(".implode(',', $onlyusfids).") AND t.uid='{$mybb->user['uid']}') OR t.fid NOT IN(".implode(',', $onlyusfids)."))";
}
```

Comment: Where clause has been posted in the question.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong here..? Why someone voted it down ?? :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually working out perfectly, you just need to group `threads`. Try this:

```
$query = $db->query("
    SELECT a.thumbnail, t.tid, t.subject
    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."attachments a
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts p ON(p.pid=a.pid)
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t ON(t.tid=p.tid)
    WHERE {$where_sql} {$visible}
    GROUP BY t.tid
    ORDER BY t.dateline DESC, a.dateuploaded ASC
    LIMIT 7
");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$QUERY = $db->QUERY("
    SELECT thumbnail, tid, subject
    FROM (SELECT a.thumbnail, t.tid, t.subject
          FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."attachments a
          INNER JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."posts p ON(p.pid=a.pid)
          INNER JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t ON(t.tid=p.tid)
          WHERE {$where_sql} {$visible}
          ORDER BY t.tid DESC, a.dateuploaded DESC
         ) AS A 
    GROUP BY tid
    LIMIT 7
");
```

Comment: It doesn't ordered by thread's date posted DESC, neither it fetches the first posted attachment.

Comment: @user2854563 Check my updated answer. Change the order by sequence. It will resolve the issue

Comment: I'm talking about the updated answer Shah bhai. It doesn't ordereing threads in DESC, nor it is fetching latest uploaded attachment

Comment: @user2854563 Can you add SQL Fiddle demo and explain me what is the problem?